# Unexpected Token } Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble passing multiple parameters to a Javascript function.

The function:

```
function selectDino(dinosaurName, dinosaurHealth, dinosaurTraits)
{
    localStorage.setItem("dinoName", dinosaurName);
    localStorage.setItem("dinoHealth", dinosaurHealth);
    localStorage.setItem("dinoTraits", dinosaurTraits);
    location.replace("nextpage.html");
}
```

....

The call (mainly the "selectDino()" bits):

```
<img class="leftDino" src="dino1.png" onmouseover = getDino("dinoOne") onclick=selectDino("dinoOne", "20", "Banterous")>
<img class="centerDino" src="dino2.png" onmouseover = getDino("dinoTwo") onclick=selectDino("dinoTwo", "18", "Spiky")>
<img class="rightDino" src="dino3.png" onmouseover = getDino("dinoThree") onclick=selectDino("dinoThree", "22", "Bitey")>
```

Whenever I look on the Chrome Developer Console, it tells me the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Can anyone help with this?

EDIT

Added single quotes around the attributes and that's fixed the problem.

Comment: You should wrap your attributes inside quotes: `onmouseover="getDino('dinoOne')" onclick="selectDino('dinoOne', '20', 'Banterous')"`

Comment: @Magicprog.fr the otherway around is nicer (and is valid html): `onmouseover = "getDino('dinoOne')" `

Comment: On the right side of the error log, should be the line number.

Comment: copy pasted code? This might be an encoding issue. Try to rewrite it

Comment: Copy/pasted the code you gave into the console. It runs fine. Your error is somewhere else in your javascript. No in the part you shared

Comment: @mguimard I've tried this, it just leads to the <img> tag line.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe No, I've written this myself.

Comment: It's most likely a syntax error. Testing your code in JSLint (http://jslint.com/) will probably tells you where it fails

Comment: I think we are supposed to close this as typo thing but yea I get it, its 2015 and SO is changing

Comment: An HTML validator would have caught this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onclick` and `onmouseover` functions needs `" "`  like that `onclick="foo();"`

```
<img class="rightDino" src="dino3.png" onmouseover="getDino('dinoThree')" onclick="selectDino('dinoThree', '22', 'Bitey')">
```

Comment: I've added quotes, and still get the same error.

Comment: Did you put the single quotes inside?

Comment: @epascarello No, I'll try that.

Comment: Yea, you can't nest the same type of quotes (`onmouseover="getDino("dinoOne")"` won't work.)

Comment: @epascarello That's worked! If only you could accept comments as answers.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: the OP seems to disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your HTML attributes in quotes, and close your HTML elements (`/>`):

```
<img class="leftDino" src="dino1.png" onmouseover="getDino('dinoOne')" onclick="selectDino('dinoOne', '20', 'Banterous')" />
<img class="centerDino" src="dino2.png" onmouseover="getDino('dinoTwo')" onclick="selectDino('dinoTwo', '18', 'Spiky')" />
<img class="rightDino" src="dino3.png" onmouseover="getDino('dinoThree')" onclick="selectDino('dinoThree', '22', 'Bitey')" />
```

Keep in mind I also changed the inner quotes to single quotes (`'`), otherwise, you'd break your HTML entirely.

Comment: In HTML5, self-closing elements : `area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr` don't need `/` at the end

Comment: @Magicprog.fr: Sure, but it's [still a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) to close your tags.